# How to properly set the module-path and module parameters when debugging / running a maven-based modular Java application in NetBeans 17?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, java-platform-module-system

I'm developing a modular Java Swing application using Java 11 (Adoptium / Temurin), Maven and Netbeans 17. My problem is reproducable even in a basic example:

The module-info.java is properly configured. Example:

```
module ModularMavenApp {
}
```

My main entry point to this app is:

```
package app;

public class ModularMavenApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ModularMavenApp.class.getModule().getName());
    }
}
```

And this is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModularMavenApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>app.ModularMavenApp</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I run / debug this application in NetBeans 17, it prints `null`! Which means, that the app runs as an unnamed module.

When I create an Ant based Java app, with the same `module-info.java` and the same main class, it prints the correct module name.

After digging deeper in my NetBeans environment I found out, that NetBeans just sets the `classpath`, but neither the `module-path` nor the `m` parameter, when starting this app.

I tried to manually setting the `module-path` and `m` (module) parameters in the project's run configuration, but then the parameter order will be `--module-path ... -m ... -Djpda.listen=true ...`. Due to the fact, that all parameters following the `-m` parameter are not parsed by the VM, but directly send to the app, this will break the debug configuration.

There's an option to manually configure the NetBeans `Run` and `Debug` actions, but I doubt, that this is the appropriate way to handle this.

So, my question is: How do I configure NetBeans to start a modular Java app as an modular Java app?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve this.

I the project's run configuration I just had to add the following VM args:
`--module-path=%classpath --add-modules=ModularMavenApp`.